# python: ..."none" type, expected integer

Tags: python, compiler-errors, integer

I've been following [tutorials on python](http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/13-lists/#pybox4) and came across a problem:

```
def middle(L):
   calc1 = (len(L))//2
   print(L[calc1])
   return
```

and the grader/compiler gave me

> "Running middle([8, 0, 100, 12, 1]) … Error: middle([8, 0, 100, 12,
>   1]) has wrong type "None" Type, expected Integer"

what i have to do is print() an element that is in the middle of a list. Although it did output a *100*.
The solution must be so simple, but i've just started learning python, let alone coding.

Comment: works fine for me, is this the original code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're printing the value but not returning it. No idea what your calling code is doing but it's clearly expecting you to do `return L[calc1]`.

Answer (score 0):

The function `middle` returns `None` (because `return` on its own means `return None`).

You're doing something with the returned value, such as `int(middle(L))`, which can't be done with `None`.

<sub>Note that you don't have to write `return` at the end of a function; it will return `None` automatically.</sub>